# Finding the adjacent of a right angle triangle with given height.

Tags: trigonometry

Given the following conditions:

- A right angled triangle
- Height is 13
- Angle a & b are not equal
- X and Y are not prime numbers.

## Is there any math formula to find X,Y, A & B?

[image]

Thank you.

Comment: Do you want all sides positive integers?

Comment: user549534 -- Have you had a chance to look at my answer below? If so any questions?

Answer (score 0):

Your triangle will be a primitive Pythagorean one since one side is $13$ and no right triangle has all three sides equal. It's known that the sides of such are $p^2-q^2,2pq,p^2+q^2$ [last being hypotenuse] where $p,q$ have gcd $1$ and $p>q.$

$13$ is odd so it must be $p^2-q^2=(p-q)(p+q)$ the only way this is $13$ is if $p-q=1,p+q=13$ leading to $p=7,q=6.$ Then the other leg is $2pq=84$ and hypotenuse $85.$
Using a rough approx. in calculator gives $A=8.8$ and $B=81.2$ [degrees] Used arctan for these and rounded.